# svn hiding changelist from status

Tags: svn, changelist

Wondering if there is a way to hide some changelist from svn status.

Basically I have a changelist with lots of files that I don't want to see. I know one can pipe the results but wondering if there is a way to do this in svn inherently.

Comment: Have a look at this: [http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.advanced.changelists.html](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.advanced.changelists.html) Scroll down to "The --changelist option acts only as a filter for Subversion command targets..." Is this what you need?

Comment: @peter_the_oak please add links to SVNBook 1.8 version.

Comment: Thx for the hint, here it is: [http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.changelists.html#svn.advanced.changelists.asfilters](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.changelists.html#svn.advanced.changelists.asfilters) Note that 1.8 is a draft, so check which one you really need.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but basically I have created Changelist called 'ignore-on-commit’: and when i do svn st I don’t want to see this list appearing as these files are generated files and there are a lot of them and it messes the view. So basically it's the opposite of svn st --changelist ignore-on-commit; (i.e. everything but this change list).